# Is Sitecore AI launched and available for use now?

Tags: personalization

I want to know whether Sitecore AI (auto personalisation) is launched already and whether it is available for use now? The below link from Sitecore says

> auto personalisation will be available from December 2019

Link : https://www.sitecore.com/company/news-events/press-releases/2019/11/sitecore-ai

- Is this available in current Sitecore releases?
- Is it only available to Sitecore's cloud offering (Sitecore Experience Cloud)

Comment: There is a very thin line being walked, when asking broadly about "more information" which we generally don't want to step close to on this site. Because of the quality of the answers however, we'll let it stand. Please refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore Cortex was released with Sitecore 9.1 which utilised AI and machine learning to drive marketing outcomes. Sitecore refers to Cortex as 'a collection of intelligent computational features available within Sitecore Experience Cloud'. Essentially you can connect your own algorithms and plug in your own machine learning.

Sitecore have since expanded upon this in Sitecore 9.3 and now have positioned Sitecore AI as a separate entity with features such as an Auto Personalization service and an AI Insights Dashboard with a view of AI optimization across the site.

There is a good whitepaper on this here: https://www.sitecore.com/resources/index/guide/the-marketers-guide-to-sitecore-ai-and-cortex-ml/-/media/BFE2FD16A8C84200A26FDFBEDC613317

So in answer to your question, it's available now in 9.3 and in the latest version - Sitecore 10.0.

Comment: Thanks! Is Sitecore AI only available in Sitecore Experience Cloud?

Comment: I believe Sitecore Experience Cloud is just an umberella term for Sitecore’s entire service offering: Sitecore Experience Management, Sitecore Experience Platform and Sitecore Commerce. So Sitecore AI and Cortext are available to all customers with an XP licence and using 9.3 and above as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

Adding few bits of information to Adam's answer from the informative whitepaper,

> The 2019 announcement of Sitecore AI was a highlight of recent new
> features in the Sitecore Experience Cloud. Sitecore AI is the new
> umbrella brand covering Sitecore’s cloud-hosted AI/ML service
> offerings, and Auto Personalization is the first service offering
> available under this brand.
>
> Sitecore AI – Auto Personalization can be installed on your cloud
> environment (Sitecore managed cloud, Azure, AWS).

[image]

Based on the above timeline diagram, Auto-personalisation and Segmentation Analysis were released on December 2019 and is available for Sitecore solutions in the cloud. Content AI and Journey AI to follow.

**NOTE :** This whitepaper was published on July, 2020.

**Reference :**
https://www.sitecore.com/resources/index/guide/the-marketers-guide-to-sitecore-ai-and-cortex-ml/-/media/BFE2FD16A8C84200A26FDFBEDC613317